# Local existence for semilinear wave equations

Tags: analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

After having done some research, I could not find a reference for the following.
Suppose I have a problem of the following type, on $(t,r) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^2$:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\square u = \partial_t^2u - \Delta u = f(\cdot, u, Du) \\
u(0) = u_0, \qquad \partial_t u (0) = u_1.
\end{array}
$$
$f$ is assumed to be smooth here.
My questions are:

- Given smooth and compactly supported initial data $(u_0, u_1)$, is it true that there is a local-in-time existence result for this equation, *such that the resulting solution is itself smooth*?
- Given smooth initial data $(u_0, u_1)$, with $\|u_0 \|_{H^1} + \| \partial_t u\|_{L^2} < C$ is it true that there is a local-in-time existence result for this equation, *such that the resulting solution is itself smooth*?

In particular, I think these results (if any) should rely on an iteration argument. I also know that, in general, $L^\infty$ bounds on the first derivatives combined with energy estimates give higher regularity. I would be really interested in understanding how (and if) the two (iteration + derivative bounds) fit together. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually, the first question is solved by Theorem 4.2 in this book: Lectures on Non-Linear Wave Equations, by Christopher Sogge. It suffices to prove a local statement which is valid in $H^s$ for all $s$. But still no idea of the second question...